# Nested routes breaks the static path

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

My css is placed inside the static directory.

html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And I have nested routes

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/user/:id', component: Profile,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'feeds',
                component: ProfileFeeds
            },
            {
                path: 'photos',
                component: ProfilePhotos
            },
        ]
    },
    ... some other routes... ,
];
```

When I am outside of the nested route, the static file is found. But, when I navigate to `user/user_21/feeds`, Vue can't find the css.

The working css:

```
http://localhost:8080/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

Turns into a wrong static path:

```
http://localhost:8080/user/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What if you link an absolute url for the css begining with a `/`?

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

Comment: Yes, that worked. Thank you. Could you please tell me why relative path didn't work?

Comment: The relative path might be relative to the current url.

Comment: Hi, not the exact same case, could you please review? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55156339/added-a-prop-with-vuerouter-and-a-css-file-stopped-loading-the-url-properly